# How to put custom <script> into my Next.Js application

Tags: javascript, next.js, frontend

I'm Developing a Next.JS application for programming school. I have a task to insert custom script into  tag of my page. Unfortunately, after pasting it inside my  tag the code breaks and all things stop working.

Here is my script:

```
<script>
!function(f,b,e,v,n,t,s)
{if(f.fbq)return;n=f.fbq=function(){n.callMethod?
n.callMethod.apply(n,arguments):n.queue.push(arguments)};
if(!f._fbq)f._fbq=n;n.push=n;n.loaded=!0;n.version='2.0';
n.queue=[];t=b.createElement(e);t.async=!0;
t.src=v;s=b.getElementsByTagName(e)[0];
s.parentNode.insertBefore(t,s)}(window, document,'script',
'https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbevents.js');
fbq('init', 'FACEBOOKKEY');
fbq('track', 'PageView');
</script>
<noscript><img height="1" width="1" style="display:none"
src=""
/></noscript>
```

Any ideas how to insert it properly?

Comment: Perhaps a Google search may do? It's in the [basic features](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/script) section of the NextJS docs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`. It looks like this and since it's an initiation for the whole project it should be inside the `_app.js`.

```
<script
  dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
    __html: `
            !function(f,b,e,v,n,t,s)
            {if(f.fbq)return;n=f.fbq=function(){n.callMethod?
            n.callMethod.apply(n,arguments):n.queue.push(arguments)};
            if(!f._fbq)f._fbq=n;n.push=n;n.loaded=!0;n.version='2.0';
            n.queue=[];t=b.createElement(e);t.async=!0;
            t.src=v;s=b.getElementsByTagName(e)[0];
            s.parentNode.insertBefore(t,s)}(window, document,'script',
            'https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbevents.js');
            fbq('init', ${YOURFACEBOOK_KEY});
          `,
  }}
/>
```

```
<noscript>
  <img
    height="1"
    width="1"
    style={{ display: "none" }}
    src={`https://www.facebook.com/tr?id=${YOURFACEBOOK_KEY}&ev=PageView&noscript=1`}
  />
</noscript>
```

Please consider not to share your keys in public places.